# Compose couple of regular expression in vscode snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I trying to build build vscode snippets based on file name. For example: from file `first.actions.ts` I'm generating `First = 42;` via `const ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*?).actions/${1:/capitalize}/g} = 42;`.

However in case when file name is e.g. `first-module.actions.ts` I'm generating `First-Module = 42;` and this code contains syntax error.  I want `const FirstModule = 42;`.

I'm looking for some trick to merge regular expression for cutting `.actions` and remove all `-` marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`"const ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([^-]*)-?(.*)\\.actions/${1:/capitalize}${2:/capitalize}/g} = 42;"`

1. capture everything up to the first `-`,
2. ignore an optional `-`, and
3. capture anything after that up to `.actions`

Assuming you want `first-module.actions.ts` => `FirstModule`

Note your extension separator `.` should be double-escaped to work properly.

Comment: Yes that's it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Good, hopefully you don't have something like `first-module-more.actions.ts` - that is, multiple hyphenated words - it won't work for more than one hyphen although I tried to find a single regex to do that unsuccessfully.  Those could be handled with a simple macro that ran two snippets though if that is necessary.

Comment: Yes, 3 kebab-case words doesn't work, however is rare case, so it can be parsed manually. Thanks again, you helped me a lot!